# style / remove Google map street direction arrows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do you style or completely remove the Google map road direction arrows ?

Here is my styles array :

```
styles:[
                {
                    "featureType": "all",
                    "elementType": "all",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "simplified"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "all",
                    "elementType": "labels",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "on"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": "-20"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "all",
                    "elementType": "labels.text",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "weight": "0.38"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "all",
                    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "saturation": 36
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "#b2a77f"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 40
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "all",
                    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "on"
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "#383838"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 16
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "all",
                    "elementType": "labels.icon",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "administrative",
                    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 20
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "administrative",
                    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 17
                        },
                        {
                            "weight": 1.2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "landscape",
                    "elementType": "geometry",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#383838"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "landscape",
                    "elementType": "labels.text",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "simplified"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                    "elementType": "all",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "on"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "poi",
                    "elementType": "geometry",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 21
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road",
                    "elementType": "labels.text",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "simplified"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road.highway",
                    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 17
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road.highway",
                    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 29
                        },
                        {
                            "weight": 0.2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road.highway",
                    "elementType": "labels.text",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "simplified"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road.arterial",
                    "elementType": "geometry",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 18
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road.arterial",
                    "elementType": "labels.text",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "road.local",
                    "elementType": "geometry",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 16
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "transit",
                    "elementType": "geometry",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "lightness": 19
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "water",
                    "elementType": "geometry",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "lightness": 17
                        },
                        {
                            "color": "#5f5b4b"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "water",
                    "elementType": "labels.text",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "water",
                    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "featureType": "water",
                    "elementType": "labels.icon",
                    "stylers": [
                        {
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

and I have tried the following :

```
disableDefaultUI: true,
streetViewControl: false,
scrollwheel: true,
panControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
overviewMapControl: false,
zoomControl: false,
draggable: true
```

Unfortunately the arrows do not disappear

[image]

Is it possible to do so ?

Thanks!

Comment: Also looking for a way to do this. I tried everything on snazzymaps.com, but no luck.

Answer (score 8):

Google Maps has now been updated to allow for the removal of the road direction arrows by setting the visibility of the `labels.icon` element.

```
{
  "featureType": "road",
  "elementType": "labels.icon",
  "stylers": [
    {"visibility": "off"}
  ]
}
```

Reference: [issue ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7884#c34)

Answer (score 6):

I did a request.
 remove the litte arrows on the road
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7884

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there are no way to disable the arrow at all.

I tried to turn off everything in the [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), however, sadly the arrows are still here...

[image: arrows]

Since the arrow is transparent and darken its area, one work around is to set the lightless to -100 so everything become black. One draw back on this is the maps become so ugly :p

[image: black]